# JMS 112 Invalid connection using spring ds

Tags: java, spring, oracle, oracle-aq

I'm using a spring datasource and is unable to connect to Oracle AQ Queue.

```
Connection connection = null;
                    AQSession aqSess = null;

                    connection = ds.getConnection();
                    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

                    DataSourceUtils.getTargetConnection(connection);
                    Class.forName("oracle.AQ.AQOracleDriver");

                    aqSess = AQDriverManager.createAQSession(connection);
                    aqSession = aqSess;
```

But still get this: `oracle.jms.AQjmsException: JMS-112: Connection is invalid` any tips would be appreciated.

```
<bean id="myId" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myIpAddress:dev"/>
      <property name="username" value="user"/>
      <property name="password" value="pass"/>
      <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
      <property name="initialSize" value="2"/>
      <property name="maxIdle" value="8"/>
      <property name="maxActive" value="30"/>
      <property name="maxWait" value="60000"/>
    </bean>


AQException: oracle.AQ.AQException: JMS-112: Connection is invalid
at oracle.AQ.AQDriverManager.createAQSession(AQDriverManager.java:193)
```

Comment: You should attache the full stack trace so we can see where the error starts (guessint is AQDriverManager but to be sure). Your configuration parameters?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem using the following code:

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
```

Recording it here as an answer in case others find this question when having a similar problem.

Comment: Doing that produces connection leak in the container. Everytime Oracle closes the connection, the datasource does not account for the close.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle AQ doesn't match with `BasicDataSource`

use`OracleDataSource` instead

but if you want to use `BasicDataSource`:

> In many application server environments the JDBC connection is wrapped
>   in an implementation specific class that delegates to the underlying
>   native JDBC connection. Oracle's AQ connection factory needs the
>   native Oracle connection and will throw an "oracle.jms.AQjmsException:
>   JMS-112: Connection is invalid" exception if the connection is wrapped
>   by a foreign class. To solve this problem you can specify a
>   NativeJdbcExtractor that can be used to unwrap the connection. Spring
>   provides a number of implementations to match the application server
>   environment. Here is an example for specifying a NativeJdbcExtractor.
>
> ```
>    <orcl:aq-jms-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
>         use-local-data-source-transaction="true"
>         native-jdbc-extractor="dbcpNativeJdbcExtractor" 1
>         data-source="dataSource" />
>
>     <bean id="dbcpNativeJdbcExtractor" 
>         class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"/>
>
> <bean id="dbcpDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" 
>         destroy-method="close">
>     <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
>     <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
>     <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
>     <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
> </bean>
> ```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/orcl.streamsaq.html